# Node js - Socket.io client is not connect to remote server

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, socket.io, client

I am trying to connect to a socket.io-client using the following code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

  console.log("Birisi bağlandı!");

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });

  socket.on('new-post', function(data){
    io.emit('posts', data);
});

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log("Birisi çıktı!");
  });


});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

Client side codes

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
        
var socket = io('http://139.59.104.188:3000');
              
</script>
```

But client side is not connect to server side. Console log is empty and i don't now why

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **socket.on('connect')** function to your client side :

```
<script>
        
var socket = io('http://139.59.104.188:3000');
             
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connected to backend');
});

</script>
```

Once your client is connected to backend, your client (=browser) console will display the message.

Comment: do you get a log server side with console.log("Birisi bağlandı!"); ?

Comment: no i don't get any console log from server side

Comment: is your backend is running correctly on correct IP defined ? and correct port 3000 ?

Comment: yes. finally i move client files to backend server. after that i run client file (index.html) on 3000 port and worked. But while client file is remote server this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try defer loading the script on the client